# Python: remove random values from multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, random, numpy-ndarray

I've created a multi-dimensional array and now I want to remove random values from `numpy.ndArray()` such that, the structure would be same, i.e. I don't want to shuffle array.

```
`array1 = [[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]`
```

edit: 
sorry for providing less info,
I want to remove elements randomly from multiple array but at same position in all arrays.

```
arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9]]
arr2 = [[11, 12, 13][14, 15, 16][17, 18, 19]]
```

after removing:

```
arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][7, 8, 9]]
arr2 = [[11, 12, 13][17, 18, 19]]
```

```
for i in random_pos:
   arr1.remove(i)
   arr2.remove(i)
```

Also want 30% elements removed from array

Comment: how do you expect the structure to same when you remove element s?

Comment: show in question what result you expect after removing random element.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan sorry I mislead you and myself

Comment: hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `random.randint` function twice. One to determine the subarray, and one to determine the element in that subarray

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
random_subarray = random.randint(len(arr))
random_item = random.randint(len(random_subarray))
del arr[random_subarray][random_item]
```